# Fiz uma sinalização, mas, a pergunta considerada como não clara?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Meu primeiro post, aqui no site foi a pergunta [Em C# como funciona a Interface IModelBinder?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151229/em-c-como-funciona-a-interface-imodelbinder), eu fui surpreendido como pergunta não clara por 5 usuários:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acabei fazendo, então, um comentário que até foi sinalizado como útil:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que até o momento não deu nenhuma chance de melhorar a pergunta e esclarecer o motivos das ações. Vejo no modo geral que outras questões bem piores (na minha opinião) são debatidas e tem a chance de melhorar, tal procedimento que não tive e também pude perceber que estou recebendo ***votos negativos sem motivos***, porque, a resposta responde a pergunta, posso até concordar que poderia ser melhorada, mas, ninguém me dê a chance e ninguém disse como, porque, etc.

***Pergunto:***

- Será que isso é válido se não me deram oportunidade de melhorar a pergunta?
- O que tem na pergunta que eu possa melhorar?
- No site eu dei uma procurada e não achei nenhuma pergunta igual ou parecida ou semelhante, não poderia ser alterado e ficar como uma pergunta válida do site?
- É melhor excluir então a pergunta?

***Observação:***

*Fiz uma sinalização é foi isso que eu recebi:*

> rejeitado - Como já foi informado antes, questionamentos sobre conteúdo devem ser feitos no meta. A moderação cuida de apenas de fraudes.A pergunta foi considerada por 5 pessoas como não clara,talvez por isso os -1

Comment: Talvez o -4 não seja justo, entretanto, sua pergunta não esta muito clara e falta mais informação (poderia ter criado o exemplo minimo e verificável) e isso dificulta para quem for responder. No titulo vc questiona como funciona a interface `IModelBinder` e em seguida diz que precisa recuperar um campo de seu formulário, vc poderia ter sido mais especifico aí. Também faltou ter postado o código HTML do formulário para facilitar, assim sabendo a estrutura do código poderia ficar melhor para alguém responder, porem o melhor caminho creio eu seria ter criado o exemplo minimo verificável mesmo.

Comment: Alem disso, ninguém tirou oportunidade de vc melhorar a pergunta, o botão **editar** fica disponível o tempo todo para vc edita-la e acrescentar mais detalhes, lembrando que vc pode fazer isso quando quiser.

Comment: @denercarvalho que muitas vezes é voto em careira, não teve intervenção nenhuma, foi lá votou e pronto. Muitos não sabem nem o que fecham simplesmente fecham. Eu sinto isso em muitas respostas em outras que são até piores são salvas. Dois pesos e duas medidas.

Comment: *"Muitos não sabem nem o que fecham simplesmente fecham"* -  você tem provas dessa afirmação? Muito cuidado com o que afirma sobre outros membros. Não é a toa que se precisa de tanta reputação para poder acessar tais filas.

Comment: E como o @DenerCarvalho já disse, o fechamento não te impede de editar a pergunta e melhorar, seguindo as recomendações descritas no quadro amarelo.

Comment: @diegofm provas não é tão difícil, mas, eu ando percebendo isso e reputação é um direito que muitas vezes é mau utilizado, como é um debate percebo que os usuários não tem a tag que corresponde as questões e mesmo assim  fecham, não que isso impede de fechar mas seria um ponto que prejudica ao meu ver o andamento intelectual. Mesmo não sendo difícil apontar não vou, a idéia é saber o motivos reais do fechamento e reabrir para ficar como conhecimento para os demais sendo que no site não tem tal questão ou se não excluir a pergunta.

Comment: Se tem provas, por que não mostrá-las? Acho muito sério acusar de que tem gente que não sabe o que fecha sem provar que a pessoa realmente não sabe. Ter a tag como favorita não prova nada disso. Eu não tenho tags de android nem javascript, mas consigo entender questões dessas tags sem problemas.

Comment: @diegofm não vou, desculpas mas eu não vou...

Comment: Então sua acusação se torna completamente infudada.

Comment: @diegofm se puder responda o que esta na pergunta. Se não eu agradeço obrigado. Respeito seu ponto de vista

Comment: O @DenerCarvalho já o fez.

Comment: É... Certas ocorrências parecem ser de cunho pessoal, mas só parecem... Acho que todos aqui já tiveram perguntas fechadas ou negativadas... Bola pra frente... As vezes dá até pra ficar chateado, mas as coisas só ficaram melhores para mim, quando passei a ver certas ações como incentivo a minha melhoria... Faz parte do sistema...

Comment: Eu gostaria de entender o quão claro você acha que está a sua pergunta. Veja, não leve a mal, mas o título diz: **Como funciona a Interface IModelBinder?**, o corpo da publicação diz, entre outras coisas, **Existe um campo no meu formulário que é obrigatório ser escrito b-nome, como poderia resgatar isso em um classe?** e a resposta (postada por você mesmo) diz: **Crie uma classe e implemente a interface IModelBinder**. Eu realmente não vejo clareza nenhuma. Lendo apenas o título, me pareceu que a pergunta tivesse salvação, se você nos explicasse o contexto, da onde vem esta interface [+]

Comment: [+] o que deseja fazer com ela e a necessidade de implementá-la. A pergunta pode parecer clara pra você que está vendo o "problema" de perto e acaba sabendo os detalhes dele. Pra mim ela não só está "não clara" como está confusa e vaga.

Comment: @jbueno não é só isso outras perguntas tem as vezes muitos comentários abaixo dizendo pra melhorar e isso não teve nesse caso, e reafirmando não é pessoal ... Então é.melhor que eu exclua? Ninguém se atenta a responder o que esta nessa pergunta

Comment: Entendi o começo, mas acho que faltou um pedaço da última frase.

Comment: Quem não manja da linguagem tem que pensar bem antes de votar em fechar uma pergunta representada pela TAG da linguagem que ele não entende nada ou não tão bem.

Comment: Já vi muitas perguntas aqui no SOpt do tipo: como funciona tal comando, tal algoritmo, tal função, tal isso, tal aquilo **sem nenhuma linha de código**. E essa que tem código e uma simples pergunta foi votada pra fechar.

Comment: E todos que votaram para fechar não descreveu o porquê e não respondeu o comentário do AP sobre o que poderia melhorar. Querem que o AP deduza.

Comment: @Gumball Uma pergunta sem código pode ser clara e boa, e uma pergunta com código pode não ser clara e/ou não ser boa.

Comment: @bfavaretto é verdade. Nesse caso especificamente eu acho que não precisava ser fechada.

Comment: Estou chegando bem atrasado e não tive tempo e paciência de ler todos os comentários e a resposta inteira do bigown. Mas pelo que vi, o que ocorre é apenas que você não soube explicar o seu problema. O que é um **b-nome**? O que há mais no formulário? O fato do seu código ser extremamente superficial e incompleto dá a entender que você nem sabe o que está falando (sendo isso ou não verdade), o que é algo que atrai muitos votos negativos. De qualquer forma, talvez isso te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298566/custom-model-binding-with-imodelbinder

Answer (score 10):

> fui surpreendido como pergunta não clara por 5 usuários

A surpresa seja talvez porque não tinha experiência anterior com o site e não sabe como ele funciona, certo?

Não sei se seria o caso para surpresa porque você postou a mesma pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês e a recepção foi a mesma que aqui.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338307/how-to-implement-imodelbinder-interface-in-c (já apagada)

Não procurei no meta, fez a mesma reclamação lá que está fazendo aqui? Se não fez, acha que existe alguma diferença entre lá e aqui?

> acabei fazendo, então, um comentário que até foi sinalizado como útil:

É uma boa, mas em quase todos os casos isso não ajuda muito já que as pessoas que votam não costuma retornar, é uma falha do mecanismo, mas a solução traria outros problemas, então não é fácil consertar. As pessoas não são obrigadas justificar.

> que até o momento não deu nenhuma chance de melhorar a pergunta

Pode melhorar a qualquer momento, não precisa aguardar ninguém dar chance.

> pude perceber que estou recebendo **votos negativos sem motivos**

Deve existir algum motivo, as pessoas apenas não quiserem dizer. O mesmo parece ter ocorrido no SO.

> resposta responde a pergunta, posso até concordar que poderia ser melhorada, mas, ninguém me dê a chance e ninguém disse como, porque

A resposta teve apenas um negativo. Alguém achou que ela não é boa. De fato não foi dito porque, mas novamente não é uma obrigação, é só algo desejável.

Citando você mesmo:

> outras questões bem piores

Tem situações de negativos bem piores também.

Vários votos negativos aqui e no SO parece indicar que há motivos. É difícil ter tantos negativos e não ter algo errado. Claro que pode, mas precisamos de algo que confirme isso. Mesmo se fosse um negativo poderia ter algo errado. Tem quem negative porque acha que algo está errado, quando na verdade ela é que está errada e várias pessoas concordavam com isso. Já houve caso de quem fazia muito isso (falo mais abaixo).

> Será que isso é válido se não me deram oportunidade de melhorar a pergunta?

É válido, está de acordo com a regras, desde que não seja feita com a clara intenção de prejudicar alguém, é normal. Novamente a oportunidade está sempre aberta, mesmo sem o apoio de outras pessoas.

Eu acho desejável que seja informado o que pode ser feito para melhorar, mas tem casos que a pessoa também não sabe, tem casos que não quer receber retaliação. Você vai justificar todos os negativos que der?

> O que tem na pergunta que eu possa melhorar?

Em perguntas não claras o mais comum é que só a pessoa que a fez conseguir melhorar de fato. A Central de Ajuda tem dicas boas de como fazer melhores perguntas. Como sabe inglês pode aprender com um [artigo do Jon Skeet sobre escrever boas perguntas](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Talvez a pergunta precise ser melhor definida de uma forma que todos possam responder. A forma como ela foi feita parece que pergunta algo muito específico (só atende aquele usuário) ou até mesmo "encomendada", ou seja, só o autor consegue responder. Várias pessoas podem ter visto de formas diferentes desta.

> No site eu dei uma procurada e não achei nenhuma pergunta igual ou parecida ou semelhante, não poderia ser alterado e ficar como uma pergunta válida do site?

O problema não é esse. Leia o enunciado do fechamento e entenda o motivo dele. Não é questão de existir no site ou ser inválida. Ela só não está clara e nessa forma outras pessoas não conseguem responder.

[image: Fechamento]

> É melhor excluir então a pergunta?

Eu diria que não, ela não é inválida, só não clara. Fechar significa apenas isso mesmo. Nada a mais. No SO você preferiu apagar, sei lá se foi o melhor.

> Fiz uma sinalização é foi isso que eu recebi

A resposta à sinalização diz sobre a discussão do conteúdo, o qual não foi argumentado nada aqui para que as pessoas possam mudar de opinião. Aqui só há reclamação que várias pessoas estão cometendo injustiça.

> muitas vezes é voto em careira, não teve intervenção nenhuma

Foi analisado e não há indícios disto. Se acha que ocorreu deve fornecer dados que indiquem isso, nós não temos nada.

> Eu sinto isso em muitas respostas

Respeito os sentimentos, mas sentir é diferente de ser. Precisamos trabalhar com fatos, não com suposições.

> Dois pesos e duas medidas.

A comunidade não é uma entidade única, dependendo do *subset* que pegar terá uma ação diferente. Não é o ideal, mas o ideal não existe.

Nos casos que acha que merece fechamento poderá iniciá-lo onde acha que faltou, em breve quando tiver reputação. E poderá votar para reabrir onde achar que não cabe o fechamento. Precisa de outras 4 pessoas. Os moderadores só fazem quando eles estão certos que não vão errar e só revertem o que a comunidade decidiu quando fica está muito claro que houve erro de avaliação das 5 pessoas.

Mas lembre-se que fechar uma pergunta não é o fim do mundo. A pergunta continua lá.

> Muitos não sabem nem o que fecham simplesmente fecham
> provas não é tão difícil
> Mesmo não sendo difícil apontar não vou

Então isso ficou com cara de *rant*. Você quer que as pessoas digam o que pode melhorar. Então diga para as pessoas porque elas fecham errado. Como as 5 pessoas aqui erraram? No SO houver erro também?

> ficar como conhecimento para os demais sendo que no site não tem tal questão ou se não excluir a pergunta

A informação ficará como conhecimento para outras pessoas. Ainda que seja questionável se ele é útil para outras pessoas na forma colocada.

> Ninguém se atenta a responder o que esta nessa pergunta

É muito difícil responder o que não está claro. Só quem tinha todo o problema na cabeça poderia fazê-lo.

## As relações em comunidades são complicadas

Vou contar duas estórias que muitos não sabem e é bom entender que essas coisas sempre ocorrerão, e que pouco ou nada pode ser feito a não ser tentar fazer melhor na próxima vez.

Um deles é um usuário bastante ativo no site e que recebeu ou recebia negativos em quase tudo que perguntava. Teve um ou outro caso de perseguição e isso foi tratado. Mas o resto simplesmente as pessoas votavam porque não gostavam do conteúdo, mesmo que ele nem fosse tão problemático assim. Os negativos de perseguição foram invalidados, o resto ele teve que conviver. Hoje ele nem reclama mais. Sempre tenta ver o que pode melhorar, mas não chama mais atenção para o conteúdo, até porque ele pode ser ruim mesmo e aí atrai mais negativos ainda. Tem caso que a melhor coisa é ser o mais discreto possível para não piorar a situação.

O mesmo já aconteceu comigo, já tive negativos de perseguição revertidos, tive outros que pessoas ativas no site concordaram que foram injustos e outros que eu achei injusto, mas talvez eu estivesse errado e fiquei meio sozinho nessa. Nesses casos o melhor é aceitar que pode estar errado mesmo que tenha convicção que não está. E tem os casos que eu mesmo acho que teria me negativado :)

Note que uma coisa é reclamar de perseguição, outra é reclamar de negativo realmente injusto e que está plenamente correto e outra bem diferente é reclamar de qualquer negativo.

Se um monte de gente acha algo ruim, é pouco provável que o autor esteja certo. Pode ocorrer, mas é raro.

O que nos leva ao outro caso de um usuário que postava coisas que muita gente achava ruim. Ele não achava o mesmo e brigava por causa disto. Era cada vez pior. E chamava atenção para o conteúdo que muita gente achava ruim e a situação até piorava. Ele nunca entendeu e aparentemente nunca respeitou a opinião das pessoas. Ele claramente dizia que todo mundo estava errado e só o que ele dizia estava certo. Abriu vários *posts* no meta reclamando de tudo e de todos. Mas nada tinha ressonância na comunidade. Isso não deu certo. Ele criou um *karma* ruim e, em resumo, mandou apagar a conta.

Aí ele criou uma nova conta com outro nome e começou de novo. Rapidamente teve a mesma atitude, deu muita encrenca e, em resumo, acabou abandonando a conta. Até aím ele ter criado uma conta nova para começar vida nova, tudo bem. Só que ele apenas fez isso pra se livrar do *karma* ruim e manter as mesmas atitudes. Ele não era discreto, insistia na sua posição, sempre achando que só ele tinha razão, e isso nunca contribuiu para uma participação positiva. Mais ainda a credibilidade ficava abalada porque ele começava mentir, pra "provar" que ele estava certo tentava dizer que era credenciado sem ser, entre outras mentiras que eram descobertas, ele ele ficava tentando apagar rastro, esconder o que tinha feito errado, mas de forma toda atrapalhada. Criar um personagem não dá certo.

E ele fez isso outras vezes. Deve estar na 5a. ou 6a., fora as que eu ainda não sei, mas é só pesquisar mais a fundo. Hoje é mais fácil identificar sendo moderador com as ferramentas que temos disponíveis, então temos ciência de qualquer conta que ele crie. Mas por alguma razão ele acha que na próxima ninguém vai perceber.

Depois de tantas contas seria razoável esperar que ele resolveu agora ter uma nova atitude e se integrar na comunidade, entender como ela funciona, aceitar que as pessoas tem seus motivos também e que ele não acerta sempre. Mas nunca aconteceu na tentativas anteriores. Esperamos que desta vez seja diferente. Se não for, o histórico precisará ser analisado. Uma coisa é começar vida nova, outra é só se livrar do histórico e ter a mesma vida. Se é pra melhorar, ninguém vê nada errado, mas as contas não podem ser usadas como vidas de um videogame, onde não há comprometimento porque sabe que pode começar de novo sem consequências. Eu preferia que ele assumisse quem é, ficasse com essa conta e nunca mais criasse outra, até porque ficar criando tanta conta pode ser interpretado como fraude. Ele precisa aprender lidar com a responsabilidade do que faz e deixar a infantilidade pra trás.

Em casos assim ou essa pessoa está errada e precisa se adaptar, aceitar que ela não está certa sempre, ou ela está certa e a comunidade é ruim pra ela. Acho improvável que seja esse o caso, mas pode acontecer. Neste caso duvido que algo mudará e não seria saudável ela insistir em uma comunidade que ela não considera boa. Acontece... algumas pessoas não se adaptam em certos grupos.

Com isso quero dizer que é justo tentar entender o que aconteceu, ver se tem algo errado, mas cuidado para não ir além do justo. É um alerta importante para todos que estão lendo entenderem que são raros os casos de erros coletivos.

E que ninguém se engane, os moderadores estão fazendo alguma coisa com tudo que acontece. Discordar de uma sinalização é fazer alguma coisa. Exigir que só uma ação da moderação seja a certa é cair no que eu disse acima.

## O conteúdo

O que está claro para mim, com o perdão do trocadilho, é que a comunidade, representada por 5 pessoas acham a pergunta não clara. Já teve alguma explicação aqui sobre isso.

A pergunta aqui no meta não entrou muito no mérito do conteúdo. Eu não cravo, mas tendo a achar que as pessoas aqui e no SO estão corretas. Vou deixar essa discussão mais para outras pessoas. Se não ficar claro que houve um erro, acho que fica do jeito que está. Pra reverter precisa trazer bons argumentos. Não basta dizer que está tudo certo. Há outras pessoas que concordam com o AP?

Muito menos adianta dizer "eu entendo do assunto". O fato de ter feito uma pergunta que aparentemente não sabia a resposta e depois ter respondido e aceito é um indício que pode não dominar tanto o assunto. Ou a pergunta foi feita só para dar a resposta? Não tem problema em fazer isso, mas é melhor ser sincero quanto a isso e não tentar fazer de conta que não sabia. De qualquer forma a pergunta feita com intenção de dar resposta precisa ser feita de forma que todos possam responder. Se só o AP pode responder adequadamente, a pergunta é, por definição, não clara.

Talvez pra responder as pessoas teriam que prever o futuro.

## Conclusão

Espero que entenda. Eu tentei dar informações relevantes, até onde está no meu alcance no assunto, e espero que sirva para várias pessoas entenderem quando ocorre algo assim.

Entenda que as pessoas possuem uma avaliação diferente da sua. Você pode discordar, mas essa foi a decisão da comunidade. Se quiser reverter precisa apresentar argumentos que façam as pessoas entenderem melhor. Ou melhorar a pergunta. Se ela ficar clara, quem sabe outra pessoa possa responder e fornecer uma solução melhor do que você achou, afinal você não domina o assunto, outra pessoa pode ter aprendido algo mais adequado.

Comment: Eu posso melhorar a pergunta, isso não invalida essa do META?

Comment: Não, tanto que respondi para ajudar todos entenderem o que ocorre em casos assim. O meta precisa ser algo que ajude a comunidade andar melhor, que ajude todos entender como ela funciona, como ela pode ser melhorada.

Comment: Outro questionamento @bigown posso excluir e quais os problemas se assim fizer?

Comment: Excluir o que?.

Comment: A pergunta original que gerou essa pergunta do meta?

Comment: Quando a pergunta já tem uma resposta, ela não pode ser excluída. E se você ficar excluindo perguntas, acho que existe uma penalização.

Comment: Como eu disse eu não acho necessário, principalmente porque você mesmo considera que ela está ajudando outras pessoas. Não sei se teria algum problema. Apenas acho estranho você querer a pergunta aberta ou excluída. Existe um meio termo que é ela fechada. Eu considero o ideal.  Não sei e alguém consideraria destruição de conteúdo útil ou se seria normal.. Se está preocupado com a pergunta ajudar outras pessoas e acha que ela está boa conforme argumentou aqui, eu não faria isso. Eu deixaria lá. Não pode impor nada a ninguém. A remoção seria uma concordância que ela não é boa, certo?

Comment: Qual penalização @WallaceMaxters? a resposta foi minha acho que consigo excluir?

Comment: @bigown nem sempre a concordância que ela não é boa, não é isso. se a comunidade não acha que isso ajude, então, pra que continuar! não é na comunidade que devemos pensar?

Comment: Mas se a comunidade desejasse a remoção teria votado para isso, apenas fecharam e negativaram. Você argumenta que tudo está certo ali, pode ser que outras pessoas vejam e concordem com você, a situação pode reverter. Se for removido, não pode. Você defendeu seu ponto. Mudou de opinião e concorda com a comunidade?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic você na sua pergunta aqui no meta deu a entender que achou a sua pergunta e resposta útil. Você quer excluir por conta da pontuação negativo ou por que concorda que a pergunta está com os problemas descritos? Se for só por conta da pontuação, aconselho deixá-la lá mesmo. Votos negativos ou positivos mostram para os outros usuário a aceitação da pergunta (o que passar disso, creio que a moderação vá resolver uma hora)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é pontuação é como a comunidade viu e vê todo esse contexto, se a comunidade acha que tudo isso não é válido ou que nem com uma edição isso melhore, possa ser que uma exclusão resolva da melhor forma possivel tudo isso.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o bigown já deixou claro: Se a comunidade quisesse remover, teríamos votado para isso. Inclusive acho que sua pergunta realmente não está clara mesmo, porém ela não precisa ser excluída.

Comment: @bigown eu concordo com o site até me expressei mau, apesar que site é feito de pessoas que são comunidades, mas, eu não concordo em receber fechamento de uma pergunta por ser clara e eu não ter nenhuma forma de arrumar como eu faço com os demais aqui, essa pergunta foi a minha primeira pergunta, não tinha quase reputação e aos poucos nós vamos aprendendo. Eu fui até chamado de não inteligente no chat agora pouco e fico chateado com tal atitude !!! mas, a gente releva e toca a bola para frente.

Comment: A comunidade acha que uma edição pode melhorar e. A comunidade pode mudar de opinião com bons argumentos. A comunidade inteira não viu aquilo, outras pessoas podem pensar diferente. Achei essa concordância esquisita. Se não concorda nem como o fechamento é muito estranho querer remover. Tem uma forma de melhorar. Eu não entendo do assunto para ajudar, mas você pode fazer isso. Se tiver alguma coisa que te ofende pode sinalizar a moderação analisará e tomará as providências cabíveis. Não queremos que isso aconteça.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tem link ou print disso? Estou no chat desde cedo e não vi ninguem lhe faltar com o respeito. Até porque isso é repudiado lá, podendo até resultar em ban.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic quando foi isso? Eu estava no chat e não vi, ou é outro chat? Ontem me chamaram de burro em um comentario, eu li respondi que não era necessário grosseria e sai, e só ri depois. Mas se for algo grave pode tentar a FLAG.